# Concerned with login controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a masterpage in which I have a Loginname control. I have a link in masterpage which redirects to register.aspx which contains createuserwizard as follows.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/AdminMaster.Master" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.vb" Inherits="Architect.Register" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
    ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Login/Register.aspx">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

I have home.aspx page in which I login as administrator with username ram and loginname changes to ram. As admin I have to create another user. So I create a new user using createuserwizard(register.aspx). After creating the user the loginname changes from ram to username of the new user. That I dont want. ram must exist. It means loginname must be ram itself. What customization do I have to make to make loginname not change?

Answer (score 0):

The standard login controls are designed for self-registration, not for administration purposes. You've three choices, use the [Web Site Admin Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx) in VS2008, write your own user admin elements or buy/download on of the ASP.NET user admin functions that are out there.